# Android 6 Nexus 5 USB Connection problems

Tags: android, usb, windows-10, nexus-5

I upgraded to Android 6 via factory image this morning, and now I want to put some data on my nexus 5 via usb. If I connect the device, I see the Nexus 5 in the (Windows 10) explorer, but when I select that, it doesn't show me the "Internal Storage" Entry, but gives me the info "This folder is empty".

I can access to the memory by ftp, but that's just a temporary solution. Does anyone know how to fix that? Also, there aren't really "USB-Options" anymore, so I can't select things like mtp there.

Debugmode is off.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

had the same problem, so i enabled developers options, went in the line for usb configuration. it was on "MTP" so i switched in another mode then came again on MTP and it worked. Hope it will work for you

Comment: Thank you so much! It was already selected, but after changing it to another option and the back it works!

Comment: It’s under the `Networking` section → `Select USB Configuration`, i had to search a little. After fixing it, it offers this option as always via a notification when connected.

Comment: Dumb question but, where is the `Networking` section?

Comment: In the developer options, there are different sections, marked with a name. But you can scroll through them, they are not like chapters or sections

Comment: I found this solution, but the issue I have is to reselect everytime I connect the device. Anybody knows a solution to that ?

Answer (score 2):

I have a nexus 9, and Android 6.0.  You have to go into the developer options. Then under networking, you select USB. Eventhough it is already selected as MTP, just press the MTP option again.  It is frustrating that you have to repeat this every time you reconnect the device.